# How do I access transclusion slots from the transclude function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-transclude

Angular 1.5 introduced [multi-slot transclusion](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude#multi-slot-transclusion). According to [the docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.7/docs/api/ng/service/$compile#transclusion):

> the transclude object { slotA: '?myCustomElement' } maps  elements to the slotA slot, which **can be accessed via the $transclude function**

Unfortunately it doesn't give any examples of this. The only example it gives doesn't mention slots at all:

```
$transclude(function(clone, scope) {
  element.append(clone);
  transcludedContent = clone;
  transclusionScope = scope;
});
```

Can someone shed some light on how to access each slot using the $transclude function?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had similar problem, but reading source code of ng-transclude helps.
It turns out there is third argument to $transclude function, which is slot name.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngTransclude.js#L190

Simple example:

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular
  .module('app')
  .directive('dir', function () {
    return {
      transclude: {
        a: 'aT',
        b: 'bT'
      },
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
        transclude(function (content) {
          elem.append('<div>a</div>');
          elem.append(content);
        }, null, 'a');
        
        transclude(function (content) {
          elem.append('<div>b</div>');
          elem.append(content);
        }, null, 'b');
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <dir>
    <a-t>content of a</a-t>
    <b-t>content of b</b-t>
  </dir>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the second parameter that you're passing in `null` for?

Comment: Scope. You can change transclude scope to custom one if you wish so.

Comment: That is not 100% correct. The scope can be changed with the first optional (here: unused) parameter. `null` applies to the `futureParentElement` parameter. The slot parameter is correct, though. The complete declaration is `function([scope], cloneLinkingFn, futureParentElement, slotName)` (Source: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)